# Proving that the sum of any 2 vectors from a span will result in another vector is the same span.

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand why this works when I visualize the span-spaces geometrically. But how do I prove this without applying geometrical visualizations?

Let **$\left<(a,b)\right>$** be the span of vectors $a,b$ (let's say they are linearly independent).

**How do I prove** that for any **$u,v$** in the span $\left<(a,b)\right>$:

**$u +v$ is also a member of the span $\left<(a,b)\right>$.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Begin with what it means for $u, v$ to be in the span $\left<(a, b)\right>$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that if $\mathbb{u},\mathbb{v}\in span\{\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\}$, then $\exists k_i, m_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\mathbb{u}=k_1\mathbb{a}+k_2\mathbb{b}$

$\mathbb{v}=m_1\mathbb{a}+m_2\mathbb{b}$

Then $\mathbb{u}+\mathbb{v}=(k_1\mathbb{a}+k_2\mathbb{b})+(m_1\mathbb{a}+m_2\mathbb{b})$.

You can regroup terms in this equation to get your result.

Then $\mathbb{u}+\mathbb{v}=(k_1+m_1)\mathbb{a}+(k_2+m_2)\mathbb{b}$.

Clearly, $k_i + m_i\in\mathbb{R}$. So we have written $\mathbb{u}+\mathbb{v}$ as a linear combination of $\mathbb{a}$ and $\mathbb{b}$. Thus, $\mathbb{u}+\mathbb{v} \in span\{\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $u,v$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. This should show you how to write $u+v$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$